# Bash, awk, get specific string from file

Tags: awk

**Issue**

I am getting data via command `awk` from file, exactly string in `""` from `<a href="DATA">`.

Source file.

```
...

<!-- Page 18 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:956px;left:485px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="145041">145041</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:586px;left:246px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="145042">145042</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:156px;left:446px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="440332">440332</a></p>
<!-- Page 19 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:1205px;left:53px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>1&#160;790,-&#160;</b>|<a href="457710">&#160;457710</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1205px;left:634px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2 290,-&#160;</b>|<a href="464429">&#160;464429</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:924px;left:353px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2 590,-&#160;</b>|<a href="464430">&#160;464430</a></p>

...
```

Command (with help on this forum).

```
awk '/Page/ {h=$3} /-- Page 1 --/ {h="Title"} /href=/ && h {split($0,a,"\"");print h","a[6]}'
```

Results.

```
...

18,145041
18,145042
18,440332
19,457710
19,464429

...
```

Problem is, when links are on the same line, data for only first link are processed.

Example.

```
`<a href="457710">&#160;457710</a></p> | <a href="464429">&#160;464429</a></p>`
```

Output.

```
...

18,457710,

...
```

Expected output.

```
...

18,457710,
18,464429,

...
```

What is wrong in `awk` command?

Thanks for any ideas.

**Update 1**

I need take all `href`s from this input.

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:397px;left:23px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft116"><a href="237002">237002&#160;</a>|<a href="237003">&#160;237003</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:831px;left:666px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft124"><a href="230041">230041</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:855px;left:447px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft116"><a href="467173">467173</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:910px;left:36px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft116">Hmotnost:&#160;6&#160;kg&#160;|&#160;<a href="464431">464431</a></p>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:1176px;left:561px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft216"><a href="318417">318417</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:963px;left:561px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft216"><a href="338701">338701</a></p>

...
```

Command.

```
awk 'match($0,/class=\"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val)} match($0,/<a href=\"[0-9]+/){val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[^"]*\"/,"",val1);print substr(val,1,2)","val1}' test.html
```

Output.

```
11,237002
12,230041
11,467173
11,464431
21,318417
...
```

**But I need this** (for example `1,238003` is not present in result above, and first column `page` is different).

```
1,237002
1,237003
1,230041
1,467173
1,464431
2,318417

...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools for parsing HTML/XML. There are syntax-aware programs for doing that, like [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).

Answer (score 1):

As the `awk` command will only process the first hyperlink on each line, just edit the file first to suit the `awk` command:

```
sed 's/\(a href=\)/\n\1/g' data-file | awk '/page/ ....'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for idea, but it generate only pages now, not second column, content of `""` of `href`.

Comment: @genderbee, it worked fine for me, not sure why it didn't for you. Line which you showed where 2 href are coming on same line is coming in your actual Input_file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Could you try with input updated in question and let me know? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with given example, could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  gsub("</p> | ","&\n")
  $1=$1
}
match($0,/class=\"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val)
}
match($0,/<a href=\"[0-9]+/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[^"]*\"/,"",val1)
  print substr(val,1,2)","val1
  val=val1=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nope, still skipping others `href`s on line.

Comment: @genderbee, could you please try `awk 'match($0,/class=\"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[^0-9]*/,"",val)} match($0,/<a href=\"[0-9]+/){val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[^"]*\"/,"",val1);print substr(val,1,2)","val1}'  Input_file` once? I tired with your shown samples and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tried, but still same. Could you look at Update 1 in question and let me know, if the output is same for you, please? Thank you in advance.